# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<="

Tags: 20.04

I wrote a script to execute the factorial command, but I'm getting this error

```
((: 1 <= : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<=")
```

I can't fix it. The <= symbol was tried with both spaces and no spaces, but the same all the time.
Below is the entire script to which the error indicated above is displayed on the 5th line

```
!/usr/bin/bash

    i=1 #nie-zero bo tworzy iloczyn
    wynik=1 # nie-zero bo tworzy iloczyn
    while (($i <= $1))
    do
     wynik=$(($wynik * $i))
     i=$(($i + 1))
    done
    echo $wynik
```

Proszę o pomoc;(

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: First line is missing the `#` symbol in column one.

Comment: Are you actually passing any positional parameter to the script? if not, `$1` will be empty, resulting in `((1 <= ))` which will give the "missing operand" error shown.

Comment: Thank you, there was a problem here, it did not trigger the parameter, brain fog, everything is already working

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass a parameter to your script:

```
$ bash -xc 'i=1; (($i <= $1))' bash 2 ; echo $?
+ i=1
+ (( 1 <= 2 ))
0
```

but

```
$ bash -xc 'i=1; (($i <= $1))' bash ; echo $?
+ i=1
+ (( 1 <=  ))
bash: ((: 1 <= : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= ")
1
```

There is a lesson here about validating inputs...